# Comparando strings com switch em PHP

Tags: php, lógica, switch

A questão é esta:

> Uma empresa irá dar um aumento de salário aos seus funcionários de
> acordo com a categoria de cada empregado. O aumento seguirá a seguinte
> regra:
>
> - Funcionários das categorias A e H ganharão 10% de aumento sobre o salário;
> - Funcionários das categorias B, D e E ganharão 15% de aumento sobre o salário;
> - Funcionários das categorias K e R ganharão 25% de aumento sobre o salário;
> - Funcionários das categorias S ganharão 35% de aumento sobre o salário;
> - Funcionários das categorias X e Z ganharão 50% de aumento sobre o salário.
> - Funcionários das demais categorias ganharão 5% de aumento sobre o salário.
>
> Utilizando o comando "Switch", escreva um algoritmo em PHP para
> receber categoria e salário atual, em seguida exiba o salário
> reajustado de um empregado para exemplo.

Eu fiz este código:

```
<?php

$salario = 1045;
$salarioFinal = 0;
$percentagem = 0;

$categoria = 'A';

switch ($categoria) {
    case 'A' or 'H':
        $percentagem = $salario * 10 / 100;
        $salarioFinal = $salario + $percentagem;
        echo "Salário atual: $salario <br/>";
        echo "Salário final: R$ $salarioFinal";
        break;

    case 'B' or 'D' or 'E';
        $percentagem = $salario * 15 / 100;
        $salarioFinal = $salario + $percentagem;
        echo "Salário atual: $salario <br/>";
        echo "Salário final: R$ $salarioFinal";
        break;

    case 'K' or 'R';
        $percentagem = $salario * 25 / 100;
        $salarioFinal = $salario + $percentagem;
        echo "Salário atual: $salario <br/>";
        echo "Salário final: R$ $salarioFinal";
        break;

    case 'X' or 'Z';
        $percentagem = $salario * 50 / 100;
        $salarioFinal = $salario + $percentagem;
        echo "Salário atual: $salario <br/>";
        echo "Salário final: R$ $salarioFinal";
        break;

    default:
        $percentagem = $salario * 5 / 100;
        $salarioFinal = $salario + $percentagem;
        echo "Salário atual: $salario <br/>";
        echo "Salário final: R$ $salarioFinal";
        break;
}

?>
```

O problema é que ele sempre pula para a condição default retornando:

```
Salário atual: 1045
Salário final: R$ 1149.5
```

ou seja, não está comparando a string conforme a variável `$categoria = 'A';` declarada no começo do código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Não dá erro](https://ideone.com/ed15e6) (inicialmente eu achei que dava por isso respondi, na verdade o código faz exatamente o que deveria fazer, eu não sabia que o PHP permitia a sintaxe usada). Fiz de um jeito que é correto e de forma muito mais simplificada evitando repetição de código e depois de observar que não tem erro, a resposta fica só por conta da simplificação.

Todo o `switch` pode ser trocado por 1 linha, mas não alterei para não fugir do pedido no enunciado.

```
<?php
$salario = 1045;
$categoria = 'A';
switch ($categoria) {
    case 'A':
    case 'H':
        $percentagem = 10;
        break;
    case 'B':
    case 'D':
    case 'E';
        $percentagem = 15;
        break;
    case 'K':
    case 'R';
        $percentagem = 25;
        break;
    case 'X':
    case 'Z';
        $percentagem = 50;
        break;
    default:
        $percentagem = 5;
        break;
}
$salarioFinal = $salario + $salario * $porcentagem / 100;
echo "Salário atual: $salario <br/>";
echo "Salário final: R$ $salarioFinal";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/I8kmLR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ldirtgwv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/MultipleCase.php).

Entenda que o `break` é justamente para dizer que encerrou a ação selecionada no `switch`. Se não tiver um ele continua executando o que está abaixo, então ele pode aceitar múltiplos `case` com a mesma ação. Dá até para fazer uma combinação de ter uma parte igual para vários, mas ter uma parte em cada `case` individual.

Não mudei mas o ideal seria ser mais organizado e ir progredindo todos pra frente ou para trás, um deles (o `default` - 5) quebrou a sequência lógica e fica menos legível. Parte de culpa é o enunciado.